# Keep :hover color on mouse click via Jquery

Tags: jquery, colors, click, hover, jquery-animate

What I want to achieve is when users clicks on a link is for the button clicked to stay the color and not fade out when the mouse moves out of hover state.

If possible only one button receive the click color at a time.

Any help is appreciated! There is a link to JS Fiddle at the bottom.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="slide">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="slide">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="slide">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="slide">4</a></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
.slide {
  padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin:20px;
  background-color:#999; 
 }

ul li {
  float:left;          
 }
```

Jquery

```
$('.slide').click(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f09");
});

$('.slide').hover(function() {


    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#000'
    }, 300);

}, function() {
    $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: '#999'
    }, 200);

});​
```

JS Fiddle Link

http://jsfiddle.net/coltanious/wNTs7/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your code like the following should work.

In your code you're overwriting the background colour when you set the animated hover.

All you need to do is set a flag, to ensure this doesn't happen. When the element is clicked, I add a class to set its style, this also acts as a flag to ensure the colour doesn't change on hover.

```
$('.slide').click(function() {
   $(".slide").each(function(i,elem) { // clear the style first
     $(elem).removeClass("clicked");
   });//so only ONE element is coloured SELECTED
   $(this).addClass("clicked");//add the "selected" colour
});

$('.slide').hover(
   function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) //check flag
    {//then hover
     $(this).animate({
         backgroundColor: '#000'
     }, 300);
    }
   }, 
  function() {
   if(!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
     $(this).animate({
         backgroundColor: '#999'
     }, 200);
     }
    }
);​
```

You css would need to have

```
.clicked
{//set !important on the style so it overrides the .slide bg colour
    background-color:#f09 !important;
}
```

​

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNTs7/23/

Comment: Thanks Gideon! Very helpful. When I was writing this out I forgot to mention if there was a way to make it so only one button becomes the clicked color. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey Gideon, thanks again. So, the elements you listed are a bit new to me and I'm somewhat new to jquery. How can I go about learning more about this elements and when to use them?Thanks! 
$('.slide').click(function() {
    $(".slide").each(function(i,elem) { 
        $(elem).removeClass("clicked");


    });
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});

Comment: @user977842 [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes a function, its first parameter is an index `(i)` and the second is the element `(elem)`. That loops through all the elements and removes the style and then adds the clicked class to the current element clicked.

Answer (score 1):

See this version for one way to do it:

- http://jsfiddle.net/wNTs7/19/

This also solves the problem of animation "overwriting" your set color.

Here's the example code - change as needed:

```
function setColor() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#f09");
}

$('.slide').click(function() {
    setColor.call(this);    
    $(this).attr('stay-like-this', 'yes');
});

$('.slide').hover(function() {
    if($(this).attr('stay-like-this') != 'yes') {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: '#000'
        }, 300, 'swing', setColor);
    }
}, function() {
    if($(this).attr('stay-like-this') != 'yes') {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: '#999'
        }, 200, 'swing', setColor);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This version for on mouse over:

- http://jsfiddle.net/L2hy67ga/1/

JS:

```
    $('.line1 ul li > a').mouseover(function() { 
       $(this).attr('keephover','yes'); 
       $('.line1 li > a').each(function(){  
          if($(this).attr('keephover')=='yes'){
              $(this).css('background-color', '#3399CC');
          } else {
              $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
          }
          $(this).attr('keephover','');         
       });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 line1">
<ul><li>
<a href="/a">URL A</a>
</li><li>
<a href="/b">URL A</a>
</li><li>
<a href="/c">URL C</a>
</li><li>
<a href="/d">URL D</a>
</li>                                                
</ul>
</div>
```